# Opening a new command prompt and writing to it in Java

Tags: java, cmd, command, prompt

The idea behind this is that I have a main class that acts as an agent, constantly running and waiting for instructions. Then, the agent gets instructed to launch n instances of another class which plays a monitoring role.

Since each instance of the monitoring class is going to be doing heavy printing (plus the fact that the agent class also prints a little bit), I would like for each instance to have its own command window to do all its printing to.

Is this possible? If not, I welcome suggestions on how to get a similar effect.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** I feel like some clarification is in order. I want to start a new command/terminal window per monitoring instance and regularly write to that window.

I would obviously love to be able to run this on any machine,  but at least I'd like to it to be able to work on Windows.

I know that there are some GUI libraries available (AWT, Swing) but I want the application to be as lightweight as possible, so that I can maximize the number of monitors that I can have on each computer. I will use a GUI library only if I have no other option.

Comment: Just to see if I understood, what you want is your application to open a new console window for each monitor class, right?

Comment: Yes, open a new console window and having each instance regularly print stuff to its window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of GUI libraries that can do what you want. AWT is one see [AWTConsoleWindow](http://kelnet.cs.unipi.gr/ganast/res/x3d/xj3d/javadoc/org/xj3d/ui/awt/widgets/AWTConsoleWindow.html). Or [this](http://code.google.com/p/lanterna/) one.

Comment: To be honest, I was trying not to use a GUI library because I want my application to be as lightweight as possible in order to maximize the number of monitoring instances that I can run. I will consider it if I have no other option.

Comment: I am not aware of any way that would be platform independent without using a library like this.

Comment: What about Windows specific?

Comment: You can with JNI but I really don't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if an instance is running for a long time and you may require multiple of those running at the same time, you will need to implement multi-threading. In particular, look into concurrency: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Next, once you figure out how to run each instance in a separate thread, you simply access Runtime:

```
Runtime RT = Runtime.getRuntime();
RT.exec("cmd.exe /c start command", null, new File(newDir)); // for example
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just execute once and leave me no way to write to that command window again?